# PYTHON: How to share folder with pip installed modules with specific users

Tags: python, module, pip, pythonpath

This is what I am trying to do. Please suggest me if there are alternative approaches to this.

I am trying to do pip install  --user --install-option="--prefix=$MYFOLDER"

I have all modules like pandas, xlsxwriter in $MYFOLDER and is usable by my user id as this is user based install.

I don't want to share these modules with all the users in system but to specific users only.

When I set PYTHONPATH=$MYFOLDER as different user still I am not able to load the modules.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A virtual environment does pretty much what you are trying to do: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Klaus good answer. But I thought virtualenv is more specific to project. What I was thinking is to set MYFOLDER in a shared folder across machines and use that FOLDER for multiple python projects across machines.

Comment: Why would you complicate matters like that? If you are deploying to a machine, keep it more self contained by having each machine have its own virtualenv. What advantages do you see by having this shared directory?

Comment: That is not a good idea. Not even even because it would create a latency and might create weird errors on network problems, it will not work if your modules are shared over different OSes, architectures, C lib versions or installations.

Comment: I don't have to install my set of modules in multiple machines individually and they are shared across environments/nodes for running the programs. So if I need to install a module across all nodes/machines, I can do the change in single environment so it is available to all machines.